# Prove that $L(V,W)$ forms a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over a field $F$. Let $L(V,W) = \{T:V\to W : T \text{ is linear} \}$, that is, $L(V,W)$ is the collection of all linear functions from $V$ to $W$. For $S,T \in L(V,W)$ and $a \in F$, define new functions $(S+T):V \to W$ and $ aT :V \to W$ by $(S+T)(x) = S(x)+T(x)$ ; $(aT)(x) = a(T(x))$.

Prove that $S+T$ belongs to $L(V,W)$ and $aT$ belongs to $L(V,W)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  For future reference, format mathematical expressions in your posts as described in [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  As for your problem: where is it that you got stuck?  Do you understand the terminology of the question, and the definitions involved?  Have you tried something that led to a dead-end?  These details help us tailor an answer to suit your needs, and let us know that you've put in the initial effort.

Comment: Try showing that the functions $\left( S+T \right) (x)$ and $ (aT)(x)$ obey the laws for linearity.  Say hi to Rankin for me.

Answer (score 2):

In order to show that $(S + T) \in L(V,W)$, we need to show that $S+T$ satisfies the defining properties of $L(V,W)$.  Clearly, $S + T$ takes a vector in $V$ and gives us a vector in $W$, so what we need to show is that $S + T$ is also **linear**.

That is, we need to show that for $v_1,v_2 \in V$ and $k \in F$, we have:
$$
(S + T)(v_1 + v_2) = (S + T)v_1 + (S + T)v_2\\
(S + T)(k v_1) = k\cdot (S + T)(v_1)
$$
In order to show that this is the case, use the definition of $S+T$ and the fact that both $S$ and $T$ are linear.

After that, do the same for $a T$.  That is, show that
$$
(aT)(v_1 + v_2) = (aT)v_1 + (aT)v_2\\
(aT)(k v_1) = k\cdot (aT)(v_1)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the definition of *linear* is central to the proof. Saying that the function $T : V \to W$ is linear means that $T$ has the following two properties:

- $T(cv) = cT(v)$ for all $c \in F$ and all $v \in V$
- $T(v_1 + v_2) = T(v_1) + T(v_2)$ for all $v_1 \in V$ and all $v_2 \in V$

**You first goal:** Given two linear functions $S : V \to W$ and $T : V \to W$, show that the function $S+T : V \to W$ is linear. To achieve the first goal, you must show that:

1. $(S+T)(cv) = c\left((S+T)(v)\right)$ for all $c \in F$ and all $v \in V$
2. $(S+T)(v_1 + v_2) = (S+T)(v_1) + (S+T)(v_2)$ for all $v_1 \in V$ and all $v_2 \in V$

**Your second goal:** Given a linear function $T : V \to W$ and a scalar $a \in F$, show that the function $aT : V \to W$ is linear. To achieve the second goal, you must show that:

3. $(aT)(cv) = c\left((aT)(v)\right)$ for all $c \in F$ and all $v \in V$
4. $(aT)(v_1 + v_2) = (aT)(v_1) + (aT)(v_2)$ for all $v_1 \in V$ and all $v_2 \in V$

These goals are the core of the proof. Once you accomplish these goals, you'll be able to write the proof through definitions of concepts.